# strange http request to aws beanstalk server

Tags: http, amazon-web-services, server

I have a node server running in aws beanstalk, and the server receives large amount of strange http requests (500 requests) every day. This triggers the server monitoring alarm, which is really annoying. I wonder where these requests come from and how I can block them.

the log looks like:

```
/var/log/nginx/access.log

172.31.51.233 - - [05/Jun/2016:03:58:07 +0000] "POST /20141201/token HTTP/1.1" 404 28 "-" "Emby/3.0.5971.0" "50.240.190.120"
172.31.51.233 - - [05/Jun/2016:03:58:07 +0000] "POST /20141201/token HTTP/1.1" 404 28 "-" "Emby/3.0.5971.0" "50.240.190.120"
172.31.51.233 - - [05/Jun/2016:03:58:08 +0000] "POST /20141201/token HTTP/1.1" 404 28 "-" "Emby/3.0.5971.0" "50.240.190.120"
172.31.51.233 - - [05/Jun/2016:03:58:08 +0000] "POST /20141201/token HTTP/1.1" 404 28 "-" "Emby/3.0.5971.0" "50.240.190.120"
```

Comment: [Emby](https://emby.media/) appears to be a media server like Plex, and it's trying to post an authentication token. Does your app have anything to do with media/videos/streaming?

Comment: No, my app has nothing to do with media/videos streaming. I am curious how they find the endpoint of my server.

Answer (score 1):

- If you know the specific ip addresses to allow in you could assign a security group to lock it down to that one set of ip addresses
- You could specifically block 50.240.190.120 with a security group entry since they are a bad actor
- If it needs to be publically accessible and you dont know what ip addresses these types of requests come from you could put a [WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/documentation/waf/) in front of the beanstalk service and screen out these requests.
- Finally you could tune your alarms to ignore 404s since being a public webservice almost certainly means you will get some amount of 404s.

Comment: WAF seems only available for AWS Cloudfront services, which I do not use.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the first field is the remote IP address.  If you want to stick your head in the sand, just drop the traffic:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT --src 172.31.51.233 -j DROP
```

But that traffic isn't coming from the internet. That network is [private](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network).

Comment: I'm guessing that IP is the ELB.

Comment: Ah, you may be right. If the OP is using ELB, then iptables is the wrong way to go.  In that case, I think the OP can deny the IP from the ELB Security Group. This way, it's not even counted as bandwidth anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to deny access from the IPs by adding rules to the Network ACLs of the AWS vps. Note Rule 400 and 500 are added to deny requests from the two specific IPs, and the added rules have to be above the default ones ( 600, and *) to be effective.

```
    Rule # Type        Protocol Port    Range Source       Allow / Deny

    400    HTTPS (443) TCP (6)  443     50.240.190.120/32  DENY
    500    HTTPS (443) TCP (6)  443     186.5.36.252/32    DENY
    600    ALL Traffic ALL      ALL     0.0.0.0/0          ALLOW 
    *      ALL Traffic ALL      ALL     0.0.0.0/0          DENY
```

Comment: those are different IPs than in your question.

Comment: They will be. The servers only see the LB IP?  assuming classic LB, you need to log the LB traffic.  The ACL block works like iptables rather than NSG so you can blacklist there.